# How to make eclipse treat a file with no extension like a java file?

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax

I have an eclipse project, and some java sources have **no extension**. When I open them in a **Java Editor**, eclipse highlights the keywords but does not have syntax/error checker.

***Question:*** How can I make eclipse **Java Editor** treat any file, as the `.java` file?

The reason I can't rename the file is because I have some external files in a directory, without extensions. I imported the directory as a source folder in a project, but I just need to edit the files now, I can not rename them.

Comment: Easiest way: rename them to .java

Comment: @immibis great solution, but unfortunately I can't, that is why I am asking this.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Well...Originally this question came from me trying to edit external lua files with no extension in eclipse, with full auto-completion (because Lua DevelopmentTools only support syntax verification and auto-completion for .lua files). But if I ask this question the way it is, it will NEVER get ANY attention. This way this question will get more attention, and might help someone else in future.

Comment: can't you just rename them to `.lua`?

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to write a script to go through everything and rename them if there are too many...

Comment: This doesn't answer why you cannot rename them.

Comment: @Victor, as part of writing a good question you should explain why renaming them doesn't work. This clarifies your context and alerts us to other hacks that may work for you *or for other people with the same problem*. I will upvote this question if you add this.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the file is used by another program. Renaming the file to `.java` and back after editing is not an option for me because I want to quickly apply changes to the file. If I had time to rename the file, and rename back for every change I make to it, and every time I want to test it, then I could rather simply have it in my project, and copy-paste it every time.

Comment: This is not a duplicate! The question marked as duplicate to this one talk about files with non `.java` extensions like `.xyz`, while this one is about files with no extension!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the following will help :

[image]

### Update:

As mentionned in comments, the association of **no extension files** was reported as [bug](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46297) for a long time, and didn't resolved till now.

However, in case you are using Zend Studio for Eclipse, you can find a suggestion in that [article](http://www.zerologic.com/Blog/Zend-Studio-for-Eclipse-No-file-extension-as-PHP.html):

> What a trick, indeed. Do this at your own risk. If you bork your
>   install, I'll try to help, but ultimately you're on your own.
>
> 1. Go to your Zend > Zend Studio for Exclipse 6.x > Plugins folder and look for org.eclipse.php.core. Mine was actually a .jar file. If it is
>      a jar file, simply rename the .jar to .zip and decompress. The
>      resulting directory will work the same as the .jar file. (keep the
>      .zip as a backup)
> 2. Search for the string: file-extensions
> 3. Add a comma inside the extension list. Mine looks like this: file-extensions="php,php3,php4,php5,,phtml,inc"
> 4. Save the file and start Zend Studio for Eclipse [image] It turns out that the double comma is interpreted
>      as an empty string, as it should be. But this is dirty, yep. Expect it
>      to be overwritten by your next install, etc. But all files that don't
>      have an extension will now be handled as PHP by Eclipse.

**NB:** The php code is inside an image, unfortunatly that's how the code is embedded in that article.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question being asked. Then again, I'm not sure what the question being asked is...

Comment: :) I think maybe he want to associate that file extension with the eclipse's Java editor

Comment: I have the .lua extension working. But is there a way to do the same thing only for the **no extension** files?

Comment: like instead of `*.lua` have `*`?

Comment: @Victor2748 I don't think so, there is a related issue which wasn't resolved: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46297

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this.

I'd just write a script like this.

```
public static void reExtensionize(File dir) {
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) reExtensionize(f);
        if (isJavaFile(f)) {// Check the file to see if it contains Java
                        // code
            Files.move(f.toPath(), new File(f.getAbsolutePath()
                    + ".java").toPath());
        }
    }
}
```